# Run wix custom action before installation starting

Tags: wix, wix3.5

Is there any way of running a custom action before the first UI is shown in WiX? This is because, I need to stop a task scheduler task before the starting of the installation.

Answer (score 4):

Sure, just schedule your custom action before any dialogs are called by the `InstallUISequence`. For example, if you are using any of the standard WixUI dialogs:

```
<InstallUISequence>
   <Custom Action='StopTaskScheduler' Before='PrepareDlg' />
</InstallUISequence>
```

Note: this action will not be executed elevated.